# XMLHttpRequest cannot load URL with some IPs and ports

Tags: javascript, android, xmlhttprequest

**-- HUGE EDIT DONE on 10/24 --**

I have a mobile application where the first action the user must do is to enter the IP and port of the server he wants to use for saving, getting informations, etc.

When he submits the IP and port he entered in the fields, every case is suppose to be handled, including the failure cases if he entered wrong informations, or the server is down, or his mobile phone has no network.

I will focus here on cases where the network is OK and the server too, so the problem is what the user entered in the fields.

Here is the request:

```
[...]
SOAPRequete = SOAPRequete + '</mns:' + _methode + '>' + '</SOAP-ENV:Body>' + '</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';

    console.log('A');

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    console.log('B');

    request.open("POST", "http://" + _ip + ":" + _port + "/4DSOAP", true);

    console.log('C');

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        console.log('D');
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            console.log('E');
            if (request.status == 200) {
                _callbackSuccess(request.responseXML);
            } else {
                console.log('F');
                _callbackFailure(request.responseXML);
            }
        }
    }
    request.send(SOAPRequete);
```

I tried:

1. IP *'whatever'* and port *'12345'*
2. IP *'whatever'* and port *'whocares'*
3. IP *'whatever'* and port nothing
4. IP nothing and port nothing
5. IP nothing and port *'12345'*

I tried it on two phones.

On the first phone, the callbackFailure is called in every case, which is good. The logs from 'A' to 'F' are shown.

On the second phone, the tests 1 and 3 are OK (callbackFailure called), but the tests 2, 4 and 5 stop after the log 'C'. The screen freezes then nothing else is logged (no Android, Eclipse or Chrome error).

And there is something else: in the cases that don't work on the second phone but work on the first one (2, 4 and 5), there is a log between logs 'C' and 'D' (so where it freezes on second phone):

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://whatever:Whocares/4DSOAP. Failed to start loading.

So it seems the request just cannot be done in some cases (IP not valued, port valued with a string), and the first phone calls the callbackFailure when the second phone does nothing.

Comment: I made a huge edit.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this ?

```
SOAPRequete = SOAPRequete + '</mns:' + _methode + '>' + '</SOAP-ENV:Body>' + '</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';
SOAPRequete = escape(SOAPRequete);
```

Comment: I've tried but it doesn't change anything. Indeed I've edited my question, because it seems that it works on a phone, but not on the other one.